# Mac - Refit error while booting

Tags: mac, refit

I'm currently on Macbook Air early 2015 (I think) and I'm dual booting Mac OSX Sierra and Windows 10, I got up to installing refit and when I restarted all that showed up was a blank grey screen with the refit logo and no options, I'm writting this on windows because I can hold option on boot and lets me open windows, so can you please help me.

EDIT: I can't boot into macosx

Comment: rEFIt has been abandoned since 2010. I maintain its successor project, [rEFInd.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) Although it's unclear to me what might be going wrong, I recommend you try rEFInd. You can obtain versions of rEFInd for CD-R and USB flash drive from its [downloads page,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) prepare a boot medium, and try to boot it by using the Option key. If this works, install rEFInd from OS X. If you can launch rEFInd but it acts much like rEFIt, then there may be something more seriously wrong and we'll need partition information at a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

- You did not install rEFIt on the EFI drive so the BIOS doesn't know where to look for for macOS or Windows
- You installed windows onto your main drive and so you lost your macOS once the drive was re-formatted

Comment: I know it's not the second one because before I installed refit and after I installed windows I booted into mac and it worked, so is it possible to fix?

Comment: Your first suggestion is not possible because rEFIt clearly is launching; it's just not working correctly.